# when I type apt-get -f install, I get the error message

Tags: 12.04

```
xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8) breaks xserver-xorg-video-5 and is installed.
```

Also I can not upgrade my software, It said that the package system is broken, with detail information:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

xserver-xorg-core: Depends: xserver-common (>= 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8) but 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8 is installed
```

when I issue `sudo apt-get update`, the output seems fine the source is（sorry the output has too many links that I can not post in）；http://archive.ubuntu.com

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

======================

when I issue `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, the output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-5
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

==================
when I issue 'sudo apt-get -f  install', the output is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-radeon:
    xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8) breaks xserver-xorg-video-5 and is installed.      
    xserver-xorg-video-radeon (1:6.12.1-0ubuntu2) provides xserver-xorg-video-5.
    dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-video-radeon (--configure):dependency problems leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    Errors were encountered while processing: xserver-xorg-video-radeon
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This package "breaks `xserver-xorg-video-5` makes no sense. Run in your terminal the commands `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and give here the full output. Edit your question.

Comment: I had the same issue and if memory serves me right, I entered a `apt-get -f install` followed by the same procedure. Mind you that I managed to reboot my system without having video drivers on it and it took me a few minutes to recover from that. So be extremely careful rebooting your system when it pops up error messages for xserver-xorg-core.

Comment: Just carefully check for error messages, check them with us on askubuntu *before* rebooting.

Comment: @NikTh, any updates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: After I completely remove xserver-xorg-core, I can update my system  as usual. However, the resolution and icons of the system is not good due to no proper video card installation. My ATI RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] card has no proper driver under 12.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and found that the package `xserver-xorg-video-5` is a [Debian virtual package](http://packages.debian.org/hu/sid/xserver-xorg-video-5).

Normally this package not exists in Ubuntu. If you run the command

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-5` the results will be

```
Package xserver-xorg-video-5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xserver-xorg-video-5' has no installation candidate
```

So , I assume you've added an external source (PPA) to install this package that broke your system.

What I suggest is to purge the ppa you've added with ppa-purge program.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge <ppa-name>
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you don't know what ppa should purge, purge them all. External sources (repositories) sometimes interfere with essential system packages and problems like this occurred.(system breakage)

Comment: When I issue sudo apt-get install ppa-purge                     The output is 'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-5
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).'